# eslint insists on not indenting <script> tag

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I have `'indent': ['warn', 2, { 'SwitchCase' : 1 }]` in my eslintrc rules.

However, it complains that the indentation of this code in a Vue template is wrong:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Sausage',
  }
</script>
```

Instead, it wants this:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Sausage',
}
</script>
```

I find this much uglier and harder to read — and it's inconstent with the `<template>` and `<style>` tags in the same template.

How can I tell eslint that the contents of a `<script>` tag should be indented one level?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/118

Comment: Thanks — that's fixed it. If you add that as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: On a side note, in Prettier you can do: "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": true

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your .eslintrc.js, add a rule for ["vue/script-indent"](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/script-indent.md) and turn off the "indent" rule for .vue files. There's options to configure indentation for switch statements here as well.

```js
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true
    },
    'extends': [
        'plugin:vue/essential',
        'eslint:recommended'
    ],
    rules: {
        'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
        'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
        "indent": ["error", 4],
        "vue/script-indent": ["error", 4, {
            "baseIndent": 1,
            "switchCase": 1,
            "ignores": []
        }],
        "space-before-function-paren": ["error", "never"],
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            "files": ["*.vue"],
            "rules": {
                "indent": "off"
            }
        }
    ],
    parserOptions: {
        parser: 'babel-eslint'
    }
}
```

Comment: That really helped me out! I think there is tons of people struggling with that problem, my environment is Sublime Text 3, vuejs, nuxt, eslint. Perhaps I will try "prettier" soon, since your solution might be decently working with that as well, I think

Comment: This is kind of a bummer because now eslint doesn't catch any actual indentation issues within vue files

Comment: @d512 the key rules are the "baseIndent": 1 and  turning the "indent": "off" in the overrides. With these two configured, eslint complains loudly for me when the indent isn't correct.